# How to terminate ec2 instance 1 hour after uptime

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2, cron

I want to terminate my ec2 instance between 1hour and 1h30 min (random interval) after it starts.

How can i achieve this?

Using `cron` job or `at` command

Below is the working code, But it will be good if i can do this using `crontab` instead of `sleep` command.

```
sleep $(shuf -i 3600-5400-n 1) && aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids $AWS_INSTANCE_ID --region ${region}
```

Thanks

Comment: Would you like to show us the code you have tried so far?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Updated answer :)

Comment: Sleep is a simpler way of achieving the outcome (less moving parts). Using `terminate-instances` requires a role with necessary permissions, whereas `sudo shutdown` will always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the instance starts, you could run a script (eg via User Data) that:

- Sleeps for the desired time period (eg `sleep 3600`)
- Does a shutdown (eg `sudo shutdown -h now`)

Be sure to set your termination behaviour to `Terminate` otherwise the instance will simply stop.